# Why would a Directive's link functionality get called before html render on one app and after on another?

Tags: angularjs

I am working on a rather large application and I created a separate POC project to try something out. Now I am ready to merge it back, so I have done that the problem I am running into is related to the following link...

```
link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        var firstElement = element[0];

        function updateSize() {
            $scope.height = firstElement.clientHeight
        }
        updateSize(); 
}
```

This directive is inside another directory we will call that parent directory.

In project 1 parent directory's template is rendered before the link, whereas in project 2 it is rendered after. So in project 1 the height is as expected and in project 2 the height is 0

Does anyone know what would cause this? I looked for ng-cloak and didn't see it anywhere in the code maybe that is just a css prop?

**Update**

It does look like this may be an ng-cloak issue but I am not sure where it is coming from.

On project 1 I see

```
<div class="md-inline-form md-layout-column ng-isolate-scope">
```

But on project 2 I see...

```
<div layout="column" class="md-inline-form ng-cloak ng-isolate-scope">
```

In the elements view. I will keep looking to see if I can find where this is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I had an old version of material somewhere. I copied over my angular/angular-material deps from project 1 and overwrote them on project 2 and now everything works :-)